# Referenciar al directorio de recursos Modulo/libreria de Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo un modulo de Android `aboutscreenlibrary`, que es para implementar una activity de información sobre la app.

**Modulo: aboutscreenlibrary**

Con una actividad `AboutActivity` que carga un menú para ver las novedades, que se deben obtener de `res/raw/changelog.txt` directorios:

```
res/drawable
   /layout
   /menú
   /raw/changelog.txt
        credits.txt
```

Dentro de ese modulo tengo un

```
public class CustomDialogHTML extends DialogFragment...`
    ...
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(getArguments().getString("uri", ""));            
        String fileName = uri.getHost();
        ...
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                getResources().getIdentifier(fileName,
                        "raw", getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
```

**Proyecto**

Solo llamo la actividad del modulo, en el proyecto no existe el directorio `res/raw/...` ya que en principio quería tenerlos dentro del modulo.

En modo `Debug` todo funciona correctamente, es cuando paso a `reléase` que me muestra vacío.

El error creo que está en

`getResources().getIdentifier(fileName,"raw", getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()` ya que eso hace referencia al contexto de la actividad y no del modulo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer referencia al directorio de recurso del modulo?

Comment: Desde la librería agregas un recurso y este también se encuentra en el proyecto, pero el del proyecto si tiene contenido?

Comment: Edito la pregunta para detallar más.

Comment: Ahora veo que en modo debug funciona correctamente es cuando paso a release

Comment: Me parece que he encontrado el motivo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053141/how-to-access-resources-in-a-android-library-project

Answer (score 0):

Trata esta forma obteniendo el id del recurso, si existe creando el InputStream:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
  if(resId != 0){
          //Si existe el recurso lo obtiene.
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
  }
```